# FBSDKGraphRequest skipped after being logged in through Facebook with Parse

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm currently having user's log in through Facebook using Parse like so:

```
 // Login PFUser using Facebook
    [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        SHOW_LOADING();

        // Eventually kick off a loading animation
        if (!error)
        {
            if (user)
            {
            FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil];
            [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {

                    NSLog(@"THE RESULT: %@", result);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    NSLog(@"ERROR");
                  }

               }];
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        HIDE_LOADING();
     }];
```

I get the log statement saying the user's been logged in, but the FBSDKGraphRequest get's completely skipped and there is no log statement from it at all? I can't seem to get it to get it send the FBSDKGraphRequest no matter what I do. (Tried it with obtaining invitable_friends as well but it got skipped too). By skipping I mean if I set breakpoints, it just hops right over the whole internal code of the FBSDKGraphRequest and no NSLog is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should call the request after you have login in/sign up the user.TRy again outside logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions loop.
it should work.
-Also use tagguable_friend instead of invitable_friend